# Html ActionLink Method Sometimes includes the ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have two methods on my controller

Function FollowUp(id As String) As ActionResult
and
Function Details(id As String) As ActionResult

When I write <%:Html.ActionLink("FollowUp", "FollowUp")%> the generated link does not include the id (I get /Project/FollowUp)

But when I write <%:Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details")%> the generated link does include the id (I get /Project/Details/25)

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a link for a routing that takes a parameter, if your current route data includes that variable, then the same value will be included in your URL. For example: if you had just the standard routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     null,
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And were currently at /home/index/25, then if you make a new link `@Html.ActionLink("test","testing")` then it would include the current id: /home/testing/25.
There are two ways I can think of this default id won't show up:

1) You have a different routing for "FollowUp" which doesn't include the {id} parameter.

```
routes.MapRoute(
     null,
     "Project/FollowUp",
     new { controller = "Project", action = "FollowUp" }
);
```

2) You're creating the "FollowUp" link on a page that doesn't have an id currently included in the routing. (like home/index instead of home/index/25)